# Flutter: where does package_info_plus.dart' get the version in Windows?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
String version = packageInfo!.version + '+' + packageInfo!.buildNumber;
```

I get this info from `pubspec.yaml`.

```
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.1.8+16
```

Eveything goes alright for ios, macos and android deployment.
But for windows, my application seems to not get the same version and I don't understand where it comes from (and where I should change).

Comment: You can see here https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/package_info_plus/package_info_plus_windows/lib/src/file_version_info.dart that it gets it from the `win32` package, here: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/GetFileVersionInfo.html

Comment: That's how to get it more than a direct answer but thanks :)
I didn't find the precise file where it comes from so I put a string in the main and I use it as global version.
At least, it will always stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let us dig into source code:

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/package_info_plus/package_info_plus_windows/lib/src/package_info_plus_windows.dart#L26

```
  @override
  Future<PackageInfoData> getAll() {
    final info = _FileVersionInfo(Platform.resolvedExecutable);
    final versions = info.productVersion!.split('+');
    final data = PackageInfoData(
      appName: info.productName ?? '',
      packageName: info.internalName ?? '',
      version: versions.getOrNull(0) ?? '',
      buildNumber: versions.getOrNull(1) ?? '',
      buildSignature: '',
    );
    info.dispose();
    return Future.value(data);
  }
```

Thus, both `version` and `buildNumber` comes from `_FileVersionInfo. productVersion`. Moreover, `_FileVersionInfo. productVersion` should be of the format `version+buildNumber`.

Looking at https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/package_info_plus/package_info_plus_windows/lib/src/file_version_info.dart

```
  String? get productVersion => getValue('ProductVersion');

  String? getValue(String name) {
...
          final lpSubBlock = TEXT('\\StringFileInfo\\$lang$codepage\\$name');
      final res =
          VerQueryValue(_data.lpBlock!, lpSubBlock, lplpBuffer!.cast(), puLen!);
      calloc.free(lpSubBlock);

      if (res != 0 && lplpBuffer.value != 0 && puLen.value > 0) {
        final ptr = Pointer<Utf16>.fromAddress(lplpBuffer.value);
        value = ptr.toDartString();
        break;
      }
  }
```

Thus, it is fetched from `'\\StringFileInfo\\$lang$codepage\\$name'`, where `$name` is `ProductVersion`.

Looking at our app's `windows/runner/Runner.rc`, there is one line:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
...
            VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
...
        END
    END
END
```

I guess that `ProductVersion` is what package_info_plus reads.

In short, you should specify it in `Runner.rc`'s macro:

```
#ifdef FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER
#define VERSION_AS_NUMBER FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER
#else
#define VERSION_AS_NUMBER 1,2,3,0 //<--- seems that also need to change this
#endif

#ifdef FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME
#define VERSION_AS_STRING #FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME
#else
#define VERSION_AS_STRING "1.2.3+456" //<--- HERE!!!
#endif
```

Which Flutter's official guide (https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/windows#updating-the-apps-version-number) also suggests.